# Accounts automatically merged after logging in with different credentials; lost badges and double entry in Dev Story

Tags: support, badges, merge-accounts

I logged out of Stack Overflow with Google and then logged in with my Facebook account to check if I could see myself in best monthly answer-er on my favourite tag, but instead I logged to find that my accounts had merged with each other, which I wasn't happy with, as it changed my username, profile pic, dev story and more. I found this on my timeline:

[image]

This seemed a little odd, I figured I had logged in with my Facebook account prior to my Google, but what has really annoyed me here, is that I lost 11 of my badges, 8 returned by themselves after ~5 minutes while the others I had to re-complete. I completed one of them but I forgot the others so I am stuck now. This seems like it would be a big issue especially if someone lost everything.

**UPDATE:**

I have made a [follow up question/feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363785/why-does-it-not-prompt-you-before-an-automatic-merge-of-accounts), due to the unsatisfactory answer here. Please go check it out.

Comment: The joined twice thing is odd but you can remove one of those. Badges are awarded periodically (some more frequently than others) so all badges that the combined accounts are eligible for will eventually come back if your account meets the criteria for them.

Comment: @JonClements The problem is with badges like mortorboard you won't get that back from what I've seen so far, I've deducted this from my experience with vox populi, as it requires you to do 40 votes in one day, it's not really a statistic thing that gets saved like your questions and votes - it's an instant thing rather than an overtime

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I also see you have a lot of experience at codafication

Comment: I guess this is why you should use Google Plus for all your Social Media needs. Their marketing team is getting really good at this persuasion thing...

Comment: This should double any reputation earning (and losing) as well

Comment: @VinhVO I will test that now.

Comment: This isn't just an inconvenience, but could be a massive privacy issue - people have posted on Workplace/Security/etc with throwaway accounts so it wouldn't be linked back to their real identity.  At least one of those hit something like +800 and was on the Hot Network Questions for days.

Comment: What is the criteria to merge accounts? Did they check like if you had the same email or something?

Comment: @Dzyann I've seen people say that it's because of IP, which I doubt but two people using the same pc with different logins got merged and they claimed it was because of IP. This would pose an issue for uni student's etc

Comment: @VinhVO It hasn't doubled my gain/loss, but I did start off after logging in with 2 more rep than I had before the merge

Comment: @Izkata I completely agree.

Comment: @Izkata: Can you provide a like to that Q?  I am curious.

Comment: @Izkata No, It would appear the accounts are squished together not fully merged, not seperate

Comment: Yes that is even worse than having 2 accounts of the same person merged. They should prompt the user before doing something like that.

Comment: I think in germany it wouldn't even be allowed that something like that is done without explicit user consent. They even forced facebook to allow people to make anonymous accounts.

Comment: @Dzyann  Yes, It should be mandatory.

Comment: @Tschallacka It should be consential, personally I got it the other way around I went from my real name to just random username. But others will probably get it differently

Comment: I find it interesting that we haven't gotten a response from someone who has any power to answer this... this has been a "Hot Meta Post" for two days now.

Comment: @kevinarpe [Our security auditor is an idiot. How do I give him the information he wants?](https://serverfault.com/q/293217/98401) (+2170 now) - note the comments are all "@A. Throwaway", the two accounts were only later intentionally merged together.

Comment: @Tschallacka "They even forced facebook to allow people to make anonymous accounts." - can I read about it somewhere?

Comment: Side note: you don't need to be logged in at all to see top tag scores. Just open a private / incognito browser window if you don't want to be logged in.

Comment: @AlexL it's in german http://www.t-online.de/digital/internet/id_74869142/facebook-soll-anonyme-nutzerprofile-erlauben.html

Comment: @AidanelGoste I just earnt my 2nd Yearling badge yesterday and that kind of surprises me a bit because I *did* earn minimum 200 rep in a year but it somehow gives me the badge twice, you can check it in my profile.

Comment: @VinhVO I'm not sure how long you have been on this website, but if it has been two years and in the time period of each you earnt 200 rep, you will recieve it twice, as is the case with badges such as "Good Question" and "Nice Question"

Comment: @AidanelGoste, well, 1st account: 3 years, 8 months, the 2nd one: just 1 year and a half (I don't remember exactly when for this 2nd account). I got merged accounts 2 months ago. I didn't receive the badges at the same time, first on Feb 27, the 2nd yesterday. I should have mentioned that I earnt those rep in just 3 or 4 months (not even a year).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start off, merges very often trigger a badge reset. That is not unusual, and all of the badges will be automatically re-awarded to you over the next 24 hours as long as the conditions that awarded them are still true. This is very much by-design and is how the merge process has always worked.

That aside, everything else gets combined together during a merge, including your posts, comments, votes, and developer story. I can't speak for the developers as to how complicated it would be to detect the merge and make sure that two separate "joined site" entries didn't appear like that, but the very nontrivial fix for that issue is to simply delete one of them off of your story.

**As to why your accounts got merged together in the first place:**

When you login with Facebook, they send us back a verified email address which we use to update the verified email address in our system as well. I don't know if you changed your email address with Facebook or something, but this time when you logged in, we got a different verified email than what was stored for your account. This triggered the system to update your verified email to the new one because of the login.

But... you already had another account in our system with the *same* verified email address (which was verified to be yours through a direct login with Google). Since both accounts now had the same *verified* email address attached to them, the system triggered an auto-merge to combine them together for you, because we don't support multiple accounts having the same email address.

Comment: "we don't support multiple accounts having the same email address" - perhaps we should add support for multiple accounts having the same email address? [see this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363624/accounts-automatically-merged-after-logging-in-with-different-credentials-lost?cb=1#comment-559953)

Comment: @AlexL Supporting multiple accounts with the same email is very different than support multiple accounts with different emails. There's nothing preventing a user creating an anonymous account with some other email address.

Comment: there's a difference between not supporting this use case, and agressively merging user accounts without asking the user for confirmation, which is what SE currently does. There is really no way for users to know in which cases they might get merged, and no warning before it happens.

Comment: Agreed, there should at *least* be a warning message asking if the user wants to merge their accounts and if not, force them to change their email address.

Comment: I will accept, your answer because what you say is true, but it is still stupid imo

Answer (score 0):

This is a bigger issue than "not supporting" different accounts with a verified email address in common. It's not that some feature failed to work, it's that the accounts were merged.

Of course accounts must never be automatically merged without explicit prompting and re-verification of all email addresses.

- **Wrongthink:** Someone posting on for example, Islam, or Judaism, or Christianity, or Politics may not want that account associated with their main account because it may harm their careers if bigots at their workplace become aware of their wrongthink.
- **Work email addresses**  Email addresses don't necessarily belong to the same person for life. Often at work leavers' email addresses are redirected to a team member or shared mailbox: That's my practice when I've been in charge of that.

  Should Clever Bob's replacement Stupid Joe be able to take over his 10k reputation just because Clever Bob used a work email address as an alternate login? Maybe you think Clever Bob must not be so clever, but was it really made clear to Clever Bob that this was a possibility?
- **Old or obsolete addresses:** Alternatively some freemail providers will re-issue email addresses which have not been logged into for a period of time. Unless you are affirmatively checking that the email is live every few months, you have no reason to assume it hasn't been reissued.

Comment: I think it's unfortunate that this is being downvoted at all. The current model is fundamentally flawed from the perspective of both security and common decency, for the above listed reasons and more.

Comment: @user69513 it's been down voted for the following reasons: 1. it's not an answer. 2. it's been copy and pasted from this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363785/why-does-it-not-prompt-you-before-an-automatic-merge-of-accounts)