# Why does it not prompt you before an automatic merge of accounts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, merge-accounts, privacy

This is a follow up question to [my last question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363624/accounts-automatically-merged-after-logging-in-with-different-credentials-lost) I am wondering why it does not prompt you before automatically merging your accounts. It is an issue of privacy, as it will change your username, profile pic, dev story and other things that weren't done manually. I am asking for this to be implemented as I would not have given my ***consent*** to merge the accounts.

Comment: Related on meta.stackexchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170072/204841

Comment: It's just related, not a dupe.

Comment: More related (would be a dupe if both were on the same site): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307348/323179

Comment: It wouldn't be an "automatic" merge then would it. I do agree that [automatic merges are monumentally stupid...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322755/accounts-got-merged-accidentally-or-automatically#comment342792_322761)

Comment: I agree that stackexhange should pay more attention to privacy issues. I once accidentally logged in with my facebook when I normally log in with gmail, and it SHOWED MY FACEBOOK PICTURE IN MY PROFILE WITHOUT ASKING PERMISSION! Therefore revealing my identity in questions that I had written with guaranteed anonymity. That's seriously horrible.

Comment: Of course accounts must never be automatically merged.

Someone posting on for example, Islam, or Judaism or Christianity, or Politics may not want that account associated with their main account because it may harm their careers if bigots at their workplace become aware of their wrongthink.

Comment: @Boat: That might make a good post of its own on MSE... but I bet they'd just blame Gravatar or whoever handles avatars these days.

Comment: @Aidan el Goste: If this is something "not just anyone can answer", adding the [discussion] tag to your question seems (and is) illogical and counter-productive. It's like tagging your Java question [c#] because it's a question only Java programmers can answer.

Comment: @BoltClock I added the discussion tag, so that people may discuss they're experiences with issues involving this.

Comment: ... that's [totally not what you said in your edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/363785/4), but ok.

Comment: @BoltClock What I meant by that is that it's only someone with the power to implement it can really answer, you're right though, I should have put more into that edit description

Answer (score 11):

Of course accounts must never be automatically merged without explicit prompting and re-verification of all email addresses.

- **Wrongthink:** Someone posting on for example, Islam, or Judaism, or Christianity, or Politics may not want that account associated with their main account because it may harm their careers if bigots at their workplace become aware of their wrongthink.
- **Work email addresses**  Email addresses don't necessarily belong to the same person for life. Often at work leavers' email addresses are redirected to a team member or shared mailbox: That's my practice when I've been in charge of that.

  Should Clever Bob's replacement Stupid Joe be able to take over his 10k reputation just because Clever Bob used a work email address as an alternate login? Maybe you think Clever Bob must not be so clever, but was it really made clear to Clever Bob that this was a possibility?
- **Old or obsolete addresses:** Alternatively some freemail providers will re-issue email addresses which have not been logged into for a period of time. Unless you are affirmatively checking that the email is live every few months, you have no reason to assume it hasn't been reissued.

Comment: This, isn't really an answer although you make good points here. What I'm asking is Why there isn't a prompt and if they can make it so that there is.

Answer (score 1):

The official word on this, from the Stack Exchange team, appears to be that "[**having multiple accounts is not explicitly supported by the system.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170073/275243)"  So if you're trying to convince them to change things, you *must not* begin your argument with "I should be allowed to have multiple accounts because..."  They will simply [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) it and move on.

Instead, any argument must begin from the position that merging causes problems for people who did not create multiple accounts, for example via email address recycling.  I encourage you to edit your question to focus less on consent and more on these problems.  Ideally, you would have specific anecdata from people who have been affected by said problems, and who did not create multiple accounts.

*(I do not agree with the official position, for the reasons given in Ben's answer.  I think it is wrong to merge accounts without your consent. 
 However, I think it is spectacularly unlikely that they are going to change it.)*

Comment: You seem to think I created multiple accounts, Which I did not.

Comment: I will add back the discussion tag to this post as someone removed it, even though I had it there for purpose. This doesn't really answer my question either, as I told ben: What I'm asking is Why there isn't a prompt and if they can make it so that there is.

Comment: @AidanelGoste: "Logging in with Facebook" is creating an account as far as Stack Exchange is concerned.

Comment: I know that it is, I am mainly asking this question for them to warn people about exposing they're private information to a public forum, prior to the merge(Just a pop up before you log in for example)

Comment: I'm sure it's in they're TOS that having multiple accounts isn't supported aswell.

Comment: @AidanelGoste: If you want them to change things, you use the [feature-request] tag.  If you *don't*, then you don't.

Comment: have you looked at the tags?

Comment: Yes, you have [feature-request] in the tags.  I'm giving you advice on how to get your feature request actually implemented.  If you aren't making a feature request, don't tag it like that.