# Are Developer Stories transferred when merging accounts?

Tags: support, developer-story, merge-accounts

When merging accounts on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), the process involves merging questions and answers which then also recalculates the reputation and badges of the account. The "About Me" Section is also merged as well.

So suppose I have two accounts. I have my older account (the account that will receive the merged data), and I have this account (the account that is providing the data that will be transferred).

If my older account has no Developer Story on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), and this account does have a Developer Story on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), will the Developer Story be merged?
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Developer Stories will be merged with the rest of the account, as animuson says [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363766/6083675):

> [E]verything else gets combined together during a merge, including your posts, comments, votes, and developer story.

However, the merge will create a second "Joined Stack Overflow" entry on your Developer Story timeline which you will need to delete.